# Why does `a&/.b` parse as `(a&)/.b` if `a&` has lower precedence than `x/.y`?

Tags: expression-manipulation, parsing

[The documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) says that `expr&` has *lower* precedence than `expr1 /. expr2`. Thus, parsing should start from operators with the lowest precedence, like `FormBox`, and then reach deep into the parse tree, all the way down to operators with high precedence, like raw symbols and numbers.

By this logic, `a&/.b` should be parsed like this:

1. Attempt to parse `FormBox`, then `CompoundExpression`, down to the lambda `expr&`.
2. `a&` is parsed as `Function[a]`.
3. We're done, but there's `/.b` left to parse. Yet there are no rules for `(expr1 &) /. expr2` since `expr&` has lower precedence than `expr1 /. expr2`.
4. Thus, `a&/.b` should be a syntax error.

I imagine an EBNF grammar for this "lambda+`ReplaceAll` with symbols" mini-language like this:

```
start: function
function: replace_all
 | function "&"
replace_all: symbol
 | replace_all "/." symbol
symbol: /[a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]*/
```

Apparently, this is incorrect since the Wolfram Language *can* parse this:

```
Hold[a & /. b] // TreeForm
```

[image: Parse tree]

Turns out, `a&/.b` parses as `(a&) /. b`. Doesn't this mean that `expr&` has *higher* precedence than `expr1 /. expr2`?

---

`c/.d&` parses as I'd expect:

1. Try to parse `expr1&`.
2. Here `expr1` is `c/.d`.
3. Try to parse `expr1` as something with a higher precedence, like `AddTo`, `SubtractFrom` or `ReplaceAll`.
4. `expr2 /. expr3` matches, so we get `expr2 == c` and `expr3 == d`.

Thus, the tree is:

```
Needs["CodeParser`"]
CodeParse["(a&/.b);(c/.d&)"] //. {
   ContainerNode[_, {a_}, _] -> a,
   LeafNode[_, a_, _] -> a, 
   CallNode[head_, {args__}, _] -> head[args]
   } // TreeForm
```

[image]

The left subtree is for `a&/.b` (which doesn't make sense) and the right subtree is for `c/.d&` (which seems fine).

---

- Why does `a & /. b` parse at all if `a &` has lower precedence than `x /. y`?
- What could a proper (E)BNF grammar for the mini-language of lambdas and `ReplaceAll`s look like?

Comment: I don't understand what alternative order of operations is possible, so that precedence is needed to decide between the alternatives.

Comment: @MichaelE2, the alternative "order of operations" is a syntax error: since `a&` has lower precedence, I parse it first, and that's it, there's no grammar to match `/.b`. Is this understanding incorrect? Also, since `a&/.b` is parsed as `(a&)/.b`, doesn't this imply that `a&` has _higher_ precedence than `x/.y`? For this to work, I'd need to parse the binary `/.` operator first, followed by the unary `&` operator, right?

Comment: @MichaelE2, alternative way of asking the same question: if `a&/.b` is parsed as `(a &) /. b`, which operator has higher precedence: `&` or `/.`? It seems to me that `&` has higher precedence, but the documentation says otherwise. Where's my mistake?

Comment: It makes no sense at all to take a syntactically valid parse and declare it a syntax error. I doubt any existing parser would do that. Voting to close.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion arises due to the fact that `&` is a _postfix_ operator, and `/.` is an _infix_ operator. Imagine a similar example with `Derivative` and `Map`. Looking at the [Operator Precedence Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html#17226802), `/@` has a higher precedence than `'`, yet `f'/@{1, 2, 3}` is parsed as expected to `{Derivative[1][f][1], Derivative[1][f][2], Derivative[1][f][3]}`. 

Similarly, `+` (_infix_) has higher precedence than `¬` (_prefix_), yet ``p+¬q`` is parsed ("as expected") to `Plus[p,Not[q]]`.

Comment: @domen Yes, that does seem like a plausible reason for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I never declared it a syntax error. Clearly, it's not. However, I'm misunderstanding something about the syntax so it _seems to me_ that this should be a syntax error. So I asked where my mistake is.

Comment: I don't follow. You already know (from remarks in the post) that `(a&) /. b` is a valid syntax. The confusion seems to be due to precedence of the postfix ampersand being lower than the infix `ReplaceAll` symbol `\.`. But there is no conflict here. In brief, postfix operator precedence applies to what precedes, not what follows. Also, for what it's worth, this is really a question/discussion about parsing in general, and not related Mathematica per se beyond the incidental fact that specific symbols in question come from that language.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, well, yes, turns out I don't quite understand how "fix-ness" is connected to operator precedence, so now it's a parsing question, not terribly related to Mathematica, indeed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I remember LR parsing and the role of precedence.

Grammar for the discussion at hand.  I'll assume symbols are already tokenized by the lexer or whatever. Rule 2 is irrelevant in the examples below; it is included in case parentheses come up.

```
1. E   :  Symbol[...] 
2.     : '(' E ')'
3.     : E '/.' E
4.     : E '&'
```

The columns are (1) the current input token, (2) the stack, and (3) the action that occurs based the input and stack. The number of the reduction corresponds to the production rule in the grammar with the same number. I assume that `/.` has be specified in some way to have precedence over `&`.  Precedence is a cheap way to resolve conflicts (easier and less costly than writing a grammar without conflicts, IIRC).

| Input `a /. b &` | Stack | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `a` | `{}` | Shift |
| `/.` | `{a}` | Reduce 1: E(1) -> `a` |
| `/.` | `{E(1)}` | Shift |
| `b` | `{E(1), /.}` | Shift |
| `&` | `{E(1), /., b}` | Reduce 1: E(2) -> `b` |
| `&` | `{E(1), /., E(2)}` | Shift/Reduce conflict (4/3). Precedence `/.` > `&`: Reduce 3: E(3) -> `a /. b` |
| `&` | `{E(3)}` | Shift |
| < null > | `{E(3), &}` | Reduce 4: E(4) -> `a /. b &` |
| < null > | `{E(4)}` | < done > |

"Precedence" as an add-on to the grammar is not needed here.

| Input `a & /. b` | Stack | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `a` | `{}` | Shift |
| `&` | `{a}` | Reduce 1: E(1) -> `a` |
| `&` | `{E(1)}` | Shift |
| `/.` | `{E(1), &}` | Reduce 4: E(2) -> `a &` |
| `/.` | `{E(2)}` | Shift |
| `b` | `{E(2), /.}` | Shift |
| < null > | `{E(2), /., b}` | Reduce 1: E(3) -> b |
| < null > | `{E(2), /., E(3)}` | Reduce 3: E(4) -> `a & /. b` |
| < null > | `{E(4)}` | < done > |

Precedence may have another meaning in a different context. Perhaps the problem can be examined in terms of unary v. binary, postfix v. infix (as suggested in the comments). I'm not sure how, except to say that production rule 3 in the grammar cannot be applied unless it has a valid `E` expression to the left (and to the right). It seems a stretch to say this is an infix issue, given that `&` is not a valid `E` -- to me, the problem centers on that. But if you want to say `&` is a problem because `/.` is infix, then I guess "infix" is an explanation. Whatever the point of view, rule 3 cannot (may not) be applied to `& /. b`.